# Visual Studio Android Emulator shows blank white page

Tags: xamarin, android-emulator, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-emulator

After update of `Visual Studio` to version 15.4. I recognized that the VS Android Emulator only shows a blank white page. Nothing is shown. No possibility to select emulator images. Had this anyone before ?

I already did a complete new reinstallation but the problem persist.

I already spend a day on this but couldn't find a solution. Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for your hints. I think I did investigation to find an answer for my question before I put the question but couldn't find any answer. What exactly am I doing wrong ?